# sed command returns error about Unmatched (

Tags: regex, sed, square-bracket

I need to get rid of the double square brackets, I only need them once. However I get the error below after this command:

```
sed -ri 's/("opening_hours": \[\[)(.*?)(\]\]/"opening_hours": \[\2\]/' ./foo.txt
```

Error: sed: -e expression #1, char 60: Unmatched ( or (

input(foo.txt):

```
"opening_hours": [["Pendant les expositions : le jeudi de 12h \u00e0 20h et\u00a0du vendredi au dimanche, de 12h \u00e0 18h"]]
"opening_hours": [["\u00d6ffnungszeiten: Fr-Sa, 15-7 Uhr und nach Vereinbarung", "Open hours: Fri-Sat, 3-7pm and by appointment"]]
```

expected output:

```
"opening_hours": ["Pendant les expositions : le jeudi de 12h \u00e0 20h et\u00a0du vendredi au dimanche, de 12h \u00e0 18h"]
"opening_hours": ["\u00d6ffnungszeiten: Fr-Sa, 15-7 Uhr und nach Vereinbarung", "Open hours: Fri-Sat, 3-7pm and by appointment"]
```

Comment: sed does not work with PCRE non-greedy quantifiers. `.*?`

Comment: This part is missing the closing parenthesis: `(\]\]`

Comment: The square brackets are not special in the replacement part and they don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better clarity, I suggest using two `s` commands:

```
sed 's/\[//; s/]//' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

For matching the exact brackets with your shown samples I would suggest to use following. Where I am using 2 substitutions but regex is to match more accurate brackets here.

```
sed 's/": \[\["/": [":/; s/"\]\]$/"]/'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\[([^][]*)\]/\1/' file
```

Match a `[` followed by zero or non `[` and `]` followed by a `]` and replace it by the value between the `[` and `]`.

N.B. The `[^][]` matches not a `[` or a `]`.